# Is there a faster way to write dictionary values to csv?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a dictionary that I am writing to a csv file, however I am only writing the values. I want to know if there is a faster way than using a for loop. I am using python 2.7 here is my code.

```
empty = ""

with open("parse_data.csv", "w") as f:
    for key, value in order_dic_keys.items():
        if value is None or value == "":
            empty += "" + "|"
        else:
            empty += str(value) + "|"
    f.write(empty[:])
```

As you can see I have a conditional statement to check the value. So I am unaware if there are other possibilities or if this is the best case scenario.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you're stuck with Python 2.x?

Comment: What does your `order_dic_keys` look like, an ordinary dictionary? How big are we talking and will there be any nesting? If so, how far down?

Comment: What about `DictWriter` from module `csv`? Re-inventing the wheel? Tag!

Comment: My order_dic_keys have 65 key and value pairs. As for the writer function from csv, I still need to do the conditional statement to check the values so I don't think that it would work here right? And I'm stuck on Python 2 because its what work uses.

Comment: @JThao No conditional statement is needed -- the csv package already handles the conversion of `None` into an empty string (as well as a bunch of other annoying details). You can see more details in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing to a csv file and grabbing all the values from a dictionary are two very common tasks in python, and so the language has built-in capabilities for both:

```
import csv

with open("parse_data.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
    writer.writerow(order_dic_keys.values())
```

This has a few nice properties compared to your code:

- In your code, you needed to do string handling (e.g. concatenation), while this handles that for you.
- This automatically handles annoying things to remember, like newlines at the end of your output (you actually didn't include one in your code)
- This automatically handles data that has the "|" character in it, putting it in quotes so you don't interpret it as two separate data elements
- This automatically handles data like `None` so you don't need to treat it as a special case, as you do in your code
- It would be straightforward to add a header row -- you would just add `writer.writerow(order_dic_keys.keys())` right after you create the writer object

Comment: Didn't know csv.writer already handled `None` like this. +1, obviously cleaner than my solution

Comment: What if I need to close the file with a trailing "|" ?

Comment: @JThao I guess you could simply add an empty data element at the end of your data -- `writer.writerow(order_dic_keys.values() + [""])`

Comment: This is perfect I didn't know how flexible it can be. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Without having any additional information, the following modifications will improve code style and should also improve performance (depending on size of data). On my machine, this approach provides a ~5x speed-up for a dictionary with 1 million random values and a ~15x speed-up for 5 million random values.

```
def value_to_str(value):
    return "" if value is None else str(value)

csv_data = "|".join(map(value_to_str, order_dic_keys.values()))

with open("parse_data.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(csv_data)
```

Instead of manually stepping through the dictionary with a for-loop, using [higher-order functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/higher-order-functions-in-python/) we take a [functional approach](https://realpython.com/python-functional-programming/) to creating the csv-string. This should allow the interpreter to better optimize our code.

---

**Notes:**

- Manual / Incremental string construction (`string = string + string` / `string += string`) is rather slow, try to avoid it when possible
- `empty += "" + "|"`, the empty string does nothing here --> `empty += "|"`
- You don't need to and shouldn't create `empty` inside the open file context manager. The open file context manager should only contain code that absolutely has to be there
- `empty` is only empty at initialization, it won't be empty at any other point during your program. It should not be named `empty`.
- You don't need to copy the write-string `empty[:]` when writing it to the file, simply omit the `[:]`
- As we're only using the dictionary values (not the keys), we can simply use `dict.values` instead of `dict.items`